# trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in php

Tags: php

I'm doing a website, and I've 2 different pages using similar codes but only 1 would work and the other appeared to have the error "trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in"...

editimage.php linked to search.php linked to imagetoupdate.php
updateaccount.php linked to searchEmail.php linked to accounttoupdate.php

Workable(updateaccount.php):

```
<form action="searchEmail.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" style="color:#000000" placeholder="Enter email" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" style="color:#000000" value="Search">
</form>
```

Workable(searchEmail.php):

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emailTrim = trim($email);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE Email = '$emailTrim'";

$search = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sql);

$emailfound = mysqli_num_rows($search);
        if($emailfound >= 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['MM_email'] = $email;
            header("Location:accountToUpdate.php");
        }
        else{
            echo 'Email not found';
        }
```

Workable(accounttoupdate.php):

```
$email = $_SESSION['MM_email'];
$emailTrim = trim($email);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM account WHERE Email = '$emailTrim'";

$account = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sql);
```

Not workable(editimage.php):

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search" style="color:#000000" placeholder="Enter email/photo no./date" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" style="color:#000000" value="Search">
</form>
```

Not workable(search.php):

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$searchTrim = trim($search);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM upload_data WHERE UploadedBy = '$searchTrim' OR  photoNo = '$searchTrim' OR Datetime LIKE '%$searchTrim%'";

$search = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sql);

$searchfound = mysqli_num_rows($search);
        if($searchfound >= 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['MM_image'] = $search;
            header("Location:imageToUpdate.php");
        }
        else{
            echo 'Invalid input';
        }
```

Not workable(imagetoupdate.php):

```
$search = $_SESSION['MM_image'];
$searchTrim = trim($search);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM upload_data WHERE UploadedBy = '$searchTrim' OR  photoNo = '$searchTrim' OR Datetime LIKE '%$searchTrim%'";

$image_list = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sql);
```

Comment: the error already says it: `trim expects a strong, object given`, check out `var_dump($search);` to find out, from our side we can only guess whats in it

Comment: What is `$_SESSION['MM_image']`?

Comment: show full code. Not enough here.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: Additionally you should use prepared statements with parameterized queries.

Comment: @Fred-ii- added some codes

Comment: @Sean added some codes

Comment: Can you provide the code that shows us what data you are sending? Is it through a `form`? if so, can you show the HTML so that we can see what you are sending to these scripts

Comment: Well here is your issue. In the first one you have `$_SESSION['MM_email'] = $email;`, which is essentially `$_SESSION['MM_email'] = $_POST['email'];`. But your second one you have `$_SESSION['MM_image'] = $search;` which is essentially `$_SESSION['MM_image'] = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sql);`, as you are overwriting `$search = $_POST['search'];` when you do `$search = mysqli_query ( $conn, $sql);`. So either change one of the `$search` vars, or change `$_SESSION['MM_image'] = $search;` to `$_SESSION['MM_image'] = $_POST['search'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in `search.php` . I would say you need to change this:

```
$_SESSION['MM_image'] = $search;
```

to this:

```
$_SESSION['MM_image'] = $searchTrim;
```